# How to draw geometry shapes over an asp.net image control to create image map?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-applications

I need an ASP.net control(like ImageMapControl), which makes it possible for the user to define imagemaps.

I show an image, the user can define areas (polygons would be nice, but just
rectangles is ok), and I can access these areas, save them(these position to be restored later from database) and use them to generate imagemaps.

It is to be used with maps, where the client can add information to areas of
the map, which is then displayed when the user clicks the area(Coloring the area and mouse drawing cannot be done by using ImageMap Control).

Does such a control exist, or has anyone done anything similar using javascript or jquery?

Thanks in advance.
-Shareef

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1536667/create-imagemap-with-javascript) is part of the answer to part of your question. You will have to save and recreate the image maps in subsequent loads.  I'd recommend writing a server side API for handling your basic CRUD operations.

You will have to create the parameters of what can be added/edit/deleted with some sort [of form](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form).

HTH